# php mysql - phpmyadmin DATE

Tags: php, mysql, date, phpmyadmin

i'm new to databases. I have just created my first database, so far so good. Now I looking to add time in to this.

I have certain table, when it's displayed I need it to show the table info + the date that info was added. Also possible the difference in between (5day 5hours ago) or something of the sort.

Do i need to add another column to the data table where the time will be stored? If so is there a way to auto increment that to current date? How do I go about doing that?

Not really sure where to start can someone please point me in the right direction perhaps a tutorial somewhere? Cant seem to find anything solid on this topic

Thanks a bunch!:)

Comment: "If so is there a way to auto increment that to ..."
? what do you want to say not clear

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 2):

For each record in your DB, you want to know when it has been created?

You have to add a column of type "timestamp". You can then set the default to "current_timestamp".
Note also that you can use the "on update current_timestamp". Instead of saving current time on insertion, it will do so each time your record is updated. 
If you need the 2 dates (created_at and updated_at), you'll need 2 columns. EDIT : well you can't :p

Comment: Don't forget the underscore in `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. It's required. :)

Comment: You also are restricted from to only one timestamp fields with one of the special default values. `One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.`

Comment: Seriously?! Ooops I didn't know this one. Now I understand why Symfony etc don't use it :s
@MarcusAdams, corrected too

Answer (score 0):

There is a datetime as well as a timestamp field. If you use a timestamp field you can have the field automatically populate with the timestamp of when the row was inserted.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

I suggest trying out http://sqlzoo.net/ for a gentle introduction to SQL.